# Is there a way to show tasks and calendar in a VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a custom homepage for which i am using a VF page. Is there a way to display the tasks and calendar which is available in the standard home page into a VF page?
[image]

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Here is an example of how to use a 3rd party JavaScript library to present a calendar in a Visualforce [FullCalendar using a JavaScript remoting callback](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/fullcalendar-using-a-javascript-remoting-callback/).

Comment: I was wondering if we could use the calendar already available in SF.. But i guess that is not possible. I am just going to use the calendar in homepage components outside of VF page. My need was to have calendar and tasks in 2 columns in a same row. I could have these as components in homepage layout which means they would be in 2 rows instead of 1 which i think the client can live with

Comment: You may want to investigate whether incorporating a Free App called [Side Calendar](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B50VmEAJ) into your org might not accomplish the functionality you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build a custom Task section using VF. You can use JavaScript or JQuery UI or a javascript library of your choice with VF remoting to build a custom calendar application.  I'm not sure you can use the Salesforce internal code (JS and CSS) from Calendar section in your vf page.

If you want a prebuilt Appexchange application, you can try Calendar Anything. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Hn2kEAC